# Silverlight Measure Method not working properly depending of databound object?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, printing, measure

**UPDATE II**
Problem was [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272658/silverlight-measure-method-not-working-properly-depending-of-databound-object/5311311#5311311). Thank you.

---

For a simple Silverlight printing preview engine, my XAML looks like this (excerpt):

```
<Grid>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding IntroText}" />
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}"
                    x:Name="DataItemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            Margin="0,2" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OutroText}" />
</Grid>
```

I want to ensure that everything fits on a page, therefore i have a simple method:

```
public bool FitsOnPrintPage(Size pageDimensions)
{
    Measure(new Size(pageDimensions.Width, Double.PositiveInfinity));

    return
        DesiredSize.Height <= pageDimensions.Height &&
        DesiredSize.Width <= pageDimensions.Width;
}
```

Now we have a strange problem here which I can't explain:

The bound collection `DataItems` is a generic `object` List. When containing simple strings, the `Measure(...)` method works as expected and returns a properly calculated `DesiredSize`. So far, everything is working.

However, when having a simple object like this...

```
public class DataItem
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

...and changing the TextBlock Binding to `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value1}"...` the resulting view is identical, however the `Measure(...)` method doesn't return the expected values, the height of the Items is always zero. Also not working: keep Text Binding and override `DataItem`s `ToString()` method. View working, Measure doesn't.

I was then trying to force a recalculation using methods like `InvalidateMeasure()` or `UpdateLayout()` on the DataTemplate or the whole page, without success.

Can you explain this?

**UPDATE**
Interesting: I've attached a simple custom `ValueConverter` to the TextBlock's Binding just for debugging reasons. When a `string` object is bound, I can see that `Measure(...)` is triggering the Binding - it's resolved first (i can see the debugger stepping into the ValueConverter) and measured afterwards. But when binding a custom class as described above, `Measure(...)` doesn't touch the Binding, i am stepping into the `ValueConverter`s breakpoint "later". *(Have to find out, when exactly)*

Does this help you in any kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

the problem was that the page controls were created and calculated first, and added to the displaying control after generation, because i wanted to avoid frequent UI updates. Something similar was even [suggested by Ai_boy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272658/silverlight-measure-method-not-working-properly-depending-of-databound-object/5272867#5272867), who was trying to solve the problem by using an independent `Grid` Control - unfortunately this turned out as a misleading approach. Only after the generated page control was added to the visual tree, it automatically resolves the Bindings resulting in a proper size measuring.

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is simple.. you working not in the 'silverlight way'**

In Silverligth - it dosen't mather if string fits to the screen width or not, if string dosen't fit, just set `TextBlock.Wrap` to `Wrap`...

You have problem with this becose of 'old way of thinking'...

But if you want it so much try this:

```
var ContainerGrid = new Grid(); // create grid at runtime

// !!! it's important for controlToMesure.Parent property to be NULL, if it's not
// !!! then temporary remove controlToMesure from parent container...
ContainerGrid.Children.Add(controlToMesure); // add control that you want to mesure

ContainerGrid.Measure(new Size(pageWidth, pageHeight));
ContainerGrid.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight));
ContainerGrid.UpdateLayout();

var size = ((FrameworkElement)ContainerGrid.Children[0]).DesiredSize;
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it didn't work, i even temporarily remove the `controlToMesure` from it's parent as described. For each Item Tested, size has the Height of 4 - this is the pure margin height (2 Top + 2 Bottom). While binding string still measures correctly, i guess i might have a "timing" problem here with databinding..?

Comment: Well there could be a lot of reasons.. i can say from my personal expiriense - if you try to do something that not in 'Silverlight way' you will end up with lots of bugs..

Comment: And try change this to `Measure(new Size(pageDimensions.Width, Double.PositiveInfinity));` this `Measure(new Size(pageDimensions.Width, pageDimensions.Height));`

Comment: Thanks Ai_boy, i already did the described change and found out, that the Measure methods's size parameter didn't affect the result

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code from http://silverpdf.codeplex.com/

Maybee it would help you, but you have to modify it, to make it usable.

```
private System.Windows.Size CalculeteSize()
{
  var s = new System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel()
  {
    VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center,
    HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center
  };
  var fs = FontPool.GetFontStream(Typeface.FontFamily.Source);
  s.Children.Add(new System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
  {
    Text = Text,
    FontSource = new FontSource(fs),
    FontSize = EmSize,
    FontFamily = Typeface.FontFamily,
    FontStretch = Typeface.FontStretch,
    FontStyle = Typeface.FontStyle,
    FontWeight = Typeface.FontWeight,
  });
  s.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(double.MaxValue, double.MaxValue));

  var aw = s.DesiredSize.Width;
  var ah = s.DesiredSize.Height;
  var size = new System.Windows.Size(aw, ah);

  return size;
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, but i would need to have the TextBlock's Text value right here, but i don't, it has to be bound to the DataContext object... ok, you could say that i can add a binding expression programmatically instead of setting the text - correct. But I fear that I will encouter same effect - the binding won't be resolved early enough. Further, this is going to be awful with a more advanced data template - the topic describes just a basic stage.